Why Angular httpclient use observers and not promises?
I've been looking in angular documentation, why httpClient use observers, but I didn't find a good answer.
My question is because I am working on a large project and we are looking for the most scalable way to build code.
We want to write the code as clean as possible, following all possible clean code rules but we can't understand what is the best way to handle an http request.
At first, we have 2 posibilities.

Put observable into promise... This doesn't convince us very much, because if I have to transform an observable into a promise, why does httpClient return an observable?

Example:
fruits.component.ts (.component looks very clean)

  apples: any;
  bananas: any;

  constructor(
    private fruitsService: FruitService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData()
  }

  loadData(){
    console.log('before get apples');
    this.apples = this.getApples();
    console.log('before get bananas');
    this.bananas = this.getBananas();
  }
  async getApples(){
    console.log('1');
    let apples = await this.fruitsService.getApples();
    console.log('2');
    return apples;
  }

  async getBananas(){
    console.log('1');
    let bananas = await this.fruitsService.getBananas();
    console.log('2');
    return bananas;
  }

fruits.service (this looks very dirty)
export class FruitService{

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

 getApples(){
    let url = `${Global.url}/api/apples`
    return new Promise(async (res) => {
      this.httpClient.get(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).subscribe(data => res(data));
    }) 
  }

 getBananas(){
    let url = `${Global.url}/api/bananas`
    return new Promise(async (res) => {
      this.httpClient.get(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).subscribe(data => res(data));
    }) 
  }
}

result console.logs


Use observables. This is fine, but causes problems with clean code.

fruits.component.ts
  apples: any;
  bananas: any;

  constructor(
    private fruitsService: FruitService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData()
  }

  loadData(){
    this.apples = this.getApples();
    this.bananas = this.getBananas();
  }
 getBananas(){
    this.fruitsService.getBananas().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        if(res?.status == ServerStatus.SUCCESSFUL){
          this.bananas = res?.bananas
        }
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.snackBar.open("Error Bananas", "Cerrar", {
          duration: 5000,
          panelClass: ['incorrect-snackbar']
        });
      }
    })
  }

 getApples(){
    this.fruitsService.getApples().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        if(res?.status == ServerStatus.SUCCESSFUL){
          this.apples = res?.apples
        }
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.snackBar.open("Error Apples", "Cerrar", {
          duration: 5000,
          panelClass: ['incorrect-snackbar']
        });
      }
    })
  }

fruits.service (service looks very clean and i do not repeat a very robust structure
)
export class FruitService{

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

getBananas(): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get(`${Global.url}/api/bananas`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }

getApples(): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get(`${Global.url}/api/apples`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }

}

Problem with clean code:
Doesn't follow "The Single Responsibility Principle"
For example, if i want actualice form with data, we need to wait data from endpoint...
And we would need to do this in the "next" in subscribe.
For example:
 getBananas(){
    this.fruitsService.getBananas().subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        if(res?.status == ServerStatus.SUCCESSFUL){
          this.bananas = res?.bananas
          this.setValuesForm();
        }
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.snackBar.open("Error Bananas", "Cerrar", {
          duration: 5000,
          panelClass: ['incorrect-snackbar']
        });
      }
    })
  }
setValuesForm(){
    this.formGroupBananas.patchValue(this.bananas);
  }

Then into get bananas we get bananas and call function to set values in formGroup (2 responsabilities)
If someone can help us with one good way to do this with a documentation, we will be very grateful :)
We actually uses the second way, but this cause problems with clean code, we need a more scalable way

"Why Angular httpclient use observers and not promises?" Probably because Forms, Router etc. mostly use Observables, so it's much cleaner to implement things like triggering requests after form values changed / query params changed.

@Derulo So, if I understand correctly, for example, if we detect that query string parameters have changed, we can subscribe to an observable returned by getBananas() and trigger a request with the changed filters?

Observables ARE promises.  They are also much more.  Think of it as a wrapper for a promise.

@browsermator Yes, i know, but then , why httpClient need return an observable? If I wait for a single response, it could be solved more easily if you returned a promise. There are the same thing, but there are reasons why exists an object called Observable and another object called Promise.

You'll end up saving a lot of code if you start using the .pipe, tap and catchError methods of Observable in your services.  (also you should avoid setting headers for GETs... not needed.)  You can create a global service to deal with all errors/logging for instance.  Don't think you need to use .next in your subscription either.  You can also strictly type the Observable... don't return ... return the type.

@browsermator Thank you very much for the recommendations. I use  because I think it is more efficient and scalable to modify the code in the fewest places possible. For example, if I need to add a field to the response, I only need to add this to the select query in my backend, and I don't need to touch the interfaces. I only use interfaces when it is strictly necessary, that is, when I need an object model that is used everywhere.
If I don't use the .next when I subscribe to an observable that brings information, I couldn't find a way to save the expected information in a variable.

Ex:
this.fruitsService.getBananas().subscribe( bananaResults=> {  this.bananas = bananaResults });  or call a method there that takes bananaResults... this.processBananaResults(bananaResults);  Hopefully strictly typed where front end and back end match.  You can always extend a type if that's useful, that will help also with creating less code, and you'll end up with less bugs that come about when using loose types or generics.

When compiled all those interface/type/class declarations are gone anyway... (only arrays are created when used...) typescript just helps reduce bugs at compile-time.  I create a folder for "models" where all types/interfaces/classes are defined and segregated by overall concern, so they can be re-used across components/services.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
